How to replace single characters depending on the neighbours with sed regex
I used this answer to pad the output with dots. Unfortunately this puts also dot's between words in the first column. I wanted to remove them with sed and regular expressions, but I have no idea how to match single characters depending on their neighbours when you cannot use look ahead. So basically i want
This.is.my.action ............. done

to
This is my action ............. done


Don't post links or images, just make your question standalone so it's easiest for people to help you. In this case there isn't nearly enough information in your question for us to propose a robust solution as it's not clear where the .s can appear in your target string, whether they can be adjacent, at the star/end of that string, what other chars can be before/after them, etc. and you haven't provided your attempt to solve the problem your self so there is no code for us to help you with (the purpose of this site).

It also sounds VERY much like an XY problem - you're adding .s you don't want and then asking how to remove them when your real goal should be to just not add them in the first place.

No need for lookahead, just match them and replace them by themselves.
sed 's/\([a-z]\)\.\([a-z]\)/\1 \2/g'


That would only replace the first . and even if you add g at the end would fail given input like The.is.a.test .... done since the regexp would match s.a and then couldn't match a.t as the a would have been consumed by the first match. You'd need to add a g and do the replacement twice.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's\> \| \</\n/g;y/\n / ./' file

Replace a space following a word ending or a space before a word beginning with a newline throughout the line.
Then translate newlines to spaces and spaces to periods.
N.B. The \> and \< could also be replaced by \b.
